# German C and D type visas

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a D type visa. I visited Germany for 3 months and returned to India. It has been 6 months now and as per the visa policy that visa is deactivated but not expired yet.

So, can I apply for a C type visa, so that I can visit Germany again?

Comment: Will it works if I apply for c type visa before expiry of my D type visa?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can apply.  If they think you shouldn't have both visas at the same time, they'll cancel your existing visa.

Many countries will cancel any existing visas when you apply for another visa, but since your D visa is already "deactivated," it shouldn't matter if they cancel your D visa.  Such cancellations are done "without prejudice," meaning that the cancellation was for administrative reasons and should not have any impact on subsequent applications.